# HTML5 video autoplay is not always triggered

Tags: javascript, html, video, autoplay

I'm creating an autoplay video element by JS, but its play event can't always be triggered.

```
const video = document.createElement('video')
video.src = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Big_Buck_Bunny_small.ogv'
// video.muted = true
video.loop = true
video.autoplay = true

video.addEventListener('canplay', () => {console.log('can')})
video.addEventListener('play',() => {
  console.log('playing')
  // setTimeout(() => {console.log(video.currentTime)}, 5000)
}, true)
```

https://codepen.io/drafting-dreams/pen/MWyxwRX

Comment: First problem I see is that your video isn't appended to your page

Comment: Is it necessary to add video element to my page? What I'm trying to do is to autoplay this video and draw it frame by frame onto a canvas. So I don't really want to show it on my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this line of code seems to fix the problem:

```
video.setAttribute('crossorigin', 'anonymous')
```

I also found this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) on MDN (Mozilla), it clarified the usage of the `crossorigin` attribute on image element, but it gives useful insight for video element.

Comment: It's true that Canvas doesn't like drawing data that comes from a different domain (gives a CORS security issue). You still need to mute the video's sound for `autoplay` to work.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you've commented `video.muted = true`. A video with sound can autoplay only at certain conditions (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)

Comment: Did you as well append your video? For example in codepen, at the end of the js code, add `document.body.append(video);`

Comment: Is it necessary to add video element to my page? What I'm trying to do is to autoplay this video and draw it frame by frame onto a canvas. So I don't really want to show it on my page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add:

```
video.load();
```